# Tokenize and count combined words (e.g. New York) and acronyms (e.g. U.S.A.) | nltk

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, text-mining

After having tokenized, cleaned and counted the terms frequencies on a text file I realised that many words like New York or U.S.A. were not counted correctly cause were tokenized by the code. How can I find a way to correctly count those words and others in the correct way.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
file_open= open("Training_Generic_6.csv")
files = file_open.read()
stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
new_text=files.lower()
token= word_tokenize(new_text)
filtered=[w for w in token if not w in stops if w.isalpha()]
count=Counter(filtered)
```

Moreover, I want to count names and surnames as a single term  like ("Barak Obama" would count for just one term and not two), are regular expressions necessary for that or shall I create a list with those terms and look for them in the file? A similar problem occurr for the term "Islamic State".

Comment: What you want to do is called [Named-Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition). It is, however, usually done *after* tokenisation, so you probably need to count the named multi-word expressions separately.

Comment: Thanks I tried the whole afternoon to figure it out without any luck. Would regular expression be of any help?

Comment: A Named-Entity Recognition system is not something you build in an afternoon, even if you use regular expressions. It's more like something you write a PhD thesis about. There are existing tools, however, especially if your texts are in English.

Comment: Which is the case, the articles are in english. Could you tell me more about these tools?

Comment: Please have a look at the links in the Wikipedia article and try a web search.